# equalsMethodTester.getFactoryCollection().addFactory(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeFactory())

Tags: java, junit, equals

I'd like to add a factory to  EqualsMethodTester to test time, but in the actual test, the program stuck, until run out of memory,  why

[image]

[image]

[image]

and when i run like

[image]

it gives me

[image]

so confused, please help me

Comment: You should not be posting images, please add the code instead
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: And even IF you do post images, please provide a sensible text instead of "enter image description here".  Since you're new here, please take the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre].